# Передача данных в json через Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Прошу не кидаться тухлыми помидорами...
Задача следующая, есть ESP8266 без статического, глобального ipv4.
Есть Orange Pi PC так же без статики.
Данные с ESP8266 нужно передать на апельсин. Существуют какие то бесплатные хостинги что бы я мог передать JSON к хостингу, а апельсин их подобрать на хостинге?
Или может какие то более лучшие варианты есть кроме json?

Comment: И близко не сталкивался с такими задачами, поэтому предложу что в голову взбрело, т.к. вопрос показался интересным.
Что если для этих целей использовать API telegram, google sheets или чего-то подобное? А внутри уже передавать в удобном формате.

Comment: Гугл интересный вариант, спасибо за наводку